# AngularJS watching property of factory objects - unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, watch

I would like to understand a certain behavior of AngularJS when it comes to watching changes of objects provided by a factory.

There is a different behavior depending on whether I read a property of a factory-provided object in the controller or in the html.

Compare the following 2 ways of displaying the property in the view:

```
app.controller("testController", function($scope, testFactory){
    $scope.test_obj = testFactory.read();
    $scope.test_prop = testFactory.read().prop;
});

<div>{{test_obj.prop}}</div>
<div>{{test_prop}}</div>
```

When the property changes in the testFactory, the change is updated in the view only in the first case, when the whole object is declared to scope and the property is called in the view. When the property is directly declared to the scope, it doesn't update automatically in the view.

This behavior can be observed in the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fb86p4fm/

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$scope.test_prop = testFactory.read().prop;

In the above line, the initial value of prop is 0. In javascript, numbers are copied by value, but objects/arrays are by reference. $scope.test_obj is referencing the service object, while $scope.test_prop is not.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `$scope.test_obj` is a reference to the factory's `obj` while `$scope.test_prop` is a copied value of `obj.prop`.

If you add the following to your example :

```
console.log(testFactory.read()); // output : Object {prop: 0}
console.log(testFactory.read().prop); // output 0
```

You'd see that the read method would return an object and the read().prop would return a value.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! Why does $scope.test_obj become a reference though and $scope.test_prop becomes a copy, not a reference?

Comment: Yes, I was aware that different types are being returned, an object and a value. I missed the knowledge about the first part of your answer - that when declaring variables in javascript, numbers will be copied and objects will be referenced. Thank you for your help!